# SQL Server: Is it possible to create a calculated index

Tags: sql-server, index

In SQL Server, is it possible to create an index on a calculation?

The following does *not* work for me:

```
CREATE INDEX customermonth ON customers(month(dob));
```

Some databases allow me to do this. Is there a trick to doing this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do this, but not with the syntax you used. The key is that you need to create a computed column in the table and then index that:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD MonthOfBirth AS MONTH(dob) PERSISTED;
CREATE INDEX customermonth ON customers (MonthOfBirth);
```

Computed column is SQL Server's name for what other products call a generated column, and in place of `STORED` (cf. `VIRTUAL`) we use `PERSISTED`.

See [How to create indexes on computed columns in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1702/how-to-create-indexes-on-computed-columns-in-sql-server/) by Atif Shehzad.

Naturally, this requires that you have *permission* to alter the schema of the table, and you'll need to ensure that there won't be any nasty side effects of adding a column (like breaking reports that use `SELECT * FROM customers;`)

Computed columns do not always have to be `PERSISTED` before you create an index on them. See the [documentation on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns).

Comment: I typically persist computed columns because storage is cheap, but CPU and RAM are a precious commodity.